# Connecting to remote goes through localhost

Tags: c#, proxy, httpclient, dotnet-httpclient

I've a http call from my c# console application. The url is specified inside HttpClient. However, I'd like it to not use localhost as a proxy and instead directly connect to the url I've specified. I intend to move this to a web forms application when it works.

I can currently see the calls in Fiddler so that must be configured somewhere.

Is there a way to do this?

The reason why I want to try this is because when I run a curl call

```
curl -x localhost:8888 -XPOST -d 'Metadata="123"' http://uri.uri [Visible in Fiddler. Doesn't return values.]
curl -XPOST -d 'Metadata="123"' http://uri.uri [Invisible in Fiddler. Returns values]
```

My c# http request is the same as the curl call. I can see it in Fiddler, meaning it's using localhost as proxy, and I'm not receiving any values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpClient` uses the default proxy configuration from Windows' Internet Options. So if you see the traffic from your app in Fiddler, then that means the default proxy config is pointing to Fiddler.

That is not surprising since ["Act as System Proxy on startup" is an option in Fiddler](https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/KnowledgeBase/OptionsUI#connections): it will change the Windows default proxy to itself when Fiddler starts up and change it back when Fiddler closes.

To verify that option in Fiddler, open Fiddler's options, go to the Connections tab, and see if "Act as System Proxy on startup" is selected.

Comment: Any idea why calling through the proxy doesn't return any values, though?

Comment: This fixed all my problems from the last 3 questions. Thank you, Gabriel.